# How do I get a list of closed/deleted Subversion branches across all revisions?

Tags: svn

How would I get a listing of all Subversion branches that have ever existed in a repository? For example, the contents of the /branches folder holds active/open branches, but how would I list branches under that path that have been *closed* (deleted) before the HEAD revision? Sometimes I want to review some work I did specifically in an old retired branch, but I cannot remember the revision range to locate it very easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a "quick" one-liner to iterate over a Subversion repo URL range, sort, and remove the duplicates. The output of `svn help ls` says a revision range is not allowed, so I think this might be the only way to list the past.

```
R1=1; R2=7; URL="https://.../branches" \
OUTPUT=""; \
for (( REV=$R1; REV<=$R2; ++REV )); do \
  echo "Processing revision $REV"; \
  OUTPUT="$OUTPUT\n$(svn ls $URL -r$REV 2>/dev/null;)"; \
done; \
echo -e "$OUTPUT" | sort | uniq | sed -e 's/\/$//';
```

Example output:

```
Processing revision 1
Processing revision 2
Processing revision 3
Processing revision 4
Processing revision 5
Processing revision 6
Processing revision 7

branch-deleted-in-r2
branch-deleted-in-r5
branch-stale-but-still-alive
some-branch-removed-r5
some-current-branch
```